# ABPersonSetImageData doesn't display image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, addressbook

I use ABUnknownPersonViewController to display a contact view.

I try to set an image with:

```
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"contact3.png"]);
ABPersonSetImageData(newPersonViewController.displayedPerson, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>You can't just cast an `NSData` object to a `CFDataRef`; as noted in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFDataRef), a `CFDataRef` is a "reference to an immutable CFData object", which is not the same as an `NSData` instance:</s>

```
typedef const struct __CFData *CFDataRef;
```

To create the `CFDataRef` from the `NSData` instance, you need to use the `CFDataCreate` method, passing the bytes and length:

```
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"contact3.png"]); 
CFDataRef dr = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
```

Note also that since you create the object yourself, you must also release it, following the [Core Foundation Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029); you use the `CFRelease` function to release ownership of the Core Foundation object:

```
CFRelease(dr);
```

This is similar to the Memory Management in Cocoa, and once the retain count of the Core Foundation object reaches zero it will be deallocated.

**Edit:** `Stefan` was completely right, in his comment, that `NSData` and `CFData` are also toll-free bridged on the iPhone with Cocoa-Touch as with Cocoa, so my original answer was wrong. My fault, should have edited it before.

Comment: Thank you Perspx. Good hint. I thought in Cocoa-Touch would be toll-free bridging between them (as in Cocoa). Nevertheless, I've just tried to create a fresh CFDataRef by your snippet. It's the same thing. Strange, I get no error back from ABPersonSetImageData.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. It was the image. Some of them don't work. Thanks for your help

Comment: No worries - glad you fixed it.

Comment: Also, remember to call ABAddressBookSave, or none of your changes will stick!